# What's the name of $x^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

I know that

$$f{(x)} = a^x$$

is called *exponential function* and

$$f{(x)} = x^a $$

is the *power function*.

---

But what is the name of $f{(x)} = x^x$?

Comment: "Does it matter" function

Comment: In my class I call it the "base-power" function. Students then onwards know what I am talking about, but I made up that name and it is certainly not an official name.

Comment: A self powered function. Take that physics.

Comment: The act of raising something to its own power is known as tetration, though that might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it doesn't have a nontrivial one. *It is its own name.*

Comment: Moreover, however, it's an instance of [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).